# d3.js Bubble distribution to match container dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to create a dynamic `.container` where each `circle` preserves its `size` ratio and always distributes to fit the available space of the `.container`.

How do I modify the code so that the distribution of the data points always resizes to the bounds of the `.container` while maintaining the `size` ratio of each `circle`?

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```js
(function() {
  var json = {
    call_data: [
      [
        "Lifestyle",
        1,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5bb3ce2f801fbc657f83dd57_pp-lifestyle(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Sports",
        2,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131911ad86f445cb5abc7_pp-sport(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Environment",
        8,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4bef42fff000159ba7a_pp-environ(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Medical",
        6,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4dc831e8500015fda53_pp-health(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Food",
        4,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f8c2cc78cc2d0001fd4a7e_pp-food(white).svg"
      ]
    ]
  };
  var width = 200;
  var height = 200;

  var tooltip = d3
    .select(".bubble_chart")
    .append("div")
    .classed("tooltip", true);

  var svg = d3
    .select(".bubble_chart")
    .append("svg")
    //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

  var bubble = d3.layout
    .pack()
    .size([200, 200])
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    })
    .padding(12);

  // generate data with calculated layout values
  var nodes = bubble.nodes(processData(json)).filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  }); // filter out the outer bubble

  var vis = svg.selectAll("circle").data(nodes, function(d, i) {
    return d.name + i;
  });

  vis
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.className;
    })
    .attr("r", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    });

  vis
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("x", d => -(d.r / 1.5) / 2)
    .attr("y", d => -(d.r / 1.5) / 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.img;
    })
    .attr("width", d => d.r / 1.5)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  /*
  vis
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", d => d.r / (d.r * 5 / 100))
    .text(d => d.name);
*/
  /*  vis
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", d => d.r / (d.r * 3 / 100))
    .text(d => d.value);
    */
  vis
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      tooltip
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("left", d3.event.x - tooltip.node().offsetWidth / 2 + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.y + 25 + "px").html(`
                <p>Category: ${d.name}</p>
                <p>Ordered: ${d.value}</p>
           
             `);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    });

  function processData(data) {
    var obj = data.call_data;

    var newDataSet = [];

    for (var prop in obj) {
      newDataSet.push({
        name: obj[prop][0],
        className: obj[prop][0].toLowerCase(),
        size: obj[prop][1],
        img: obj[prop][2]
      });
    }
    return {
      children: newDataSet
    };
  }

  var aspect = width / height,
    chart = d3.select('.bubble_chart');
  d3.select(window)
    .on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = chart.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", targetWidth / aspect);
    });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bubble_chart {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid
}

.lifestyle {
  fill: #89BED3;
}

.sports {
  fill: #2A83D4;
}

.environment {
  fill: #6CC070;
}

.food {
  fill: #665C9E;
}

.medical {
  fill: #C13E40;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fafafa;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bubble_chart"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your width and height to the bounding rect height and width at the outset. Right now you have it set as both 200px, which are the same.

Do that like this:

```
var width = document.querySelector(".container").getBoundingClientRect().width;  
var height = document.querySelector(".container").getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

```js
(function() {
  var json = {
    call_data: [
      [
        "Lifestyle",
        1,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5bb3ce2f801fbc657f83dd57_pp-lifestyle(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Sports",
        2,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131911ad86f445cb5abc7_pp-sport(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Environment",
        8,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4bef42fff000159ba7a_pp-environ(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Medical",
        6,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4dc831e8500015fda53_pp-health(white).svg"
      ],
      [
        "Food",
        4,
        "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f8c2cc78cc2d0001fd4a7e_pp-food(white).svg"
      ]
    ]
  };
  var width = document.querySelector(".container").getBoundingClientRect().width;  
  var height = document.querySelector(".container").getBoundingClientRect().height;

  var tooltip = d3
    .select(".bubble_chart")
    .append("div")
    .classed("tooltip", true);

  var svg = d3
    .select(".bubble_chart")
    .append("svg")
    //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

  var bubble = d3.layout
    .pack()
    .size([200, 200])
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    })
    .padding(12);

  // generate data with calculated layout values
  var nodes = bubble.nodes(processData(json)).filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  }); // filter out the outer bubble

  var vis = svg.selectAll("circle").data(nodes, function(d, i) {
    return d.name + i;
  });

  vis
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.className;
    })
    .attr("r", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r;
    });

  vis
    .enter()
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("x", d => -(d.r / 1.5) / 2)
    .attr("y", d => -(d.r / 1.5) / 2)
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.img;
    })
    .attr("width", d => d.r / 1.5)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  /*
  vis
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", d => d.r / (d.r * 5 / 100))
    .text(d => d.name);
*/
  /*  vis
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", d => d.r / (d.r * 3 / 100))
    .text(d => d.value);
    */
  vis
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
      tooltip
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("left", d3.event.x - tooltip.node().offsetWidth / 2 + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.y + 25 + "px").html(`
                <p>Category: ${d.name}</p>
                <p>Ordered: ${d.value}</p>
           
             `);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    });

  function processData(data) {
    var obj = data.call_data;

    var newDataSet = [];

    for (var prop in obj) {
      newDataSet.push({
        name: obj[prop][0],
        className: obj[prop][0].toLowerCase(),
        size: obj[prop][1],
        img: obj[prop][2]
      });
    }
    return {
      children: newDataSet
    };
  }

  var aspect = width / height,
    chart = d3.select('.bubble_chart');
  d3.select(window)
    .on("resize", function() {
      var targetWidth = chart.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
      chart.attr("height", targetWidth / aspect);
    });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.bubble_chart {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid
}

.lifestyle {
  fill: #89BED3;
}

.sports {
  fill: #2A83D4;
}

.environment {
  fill: #6CC070;
}

.food {
  fill: #665C9E;
}

.medical {
  fill: #C13E40;
}

.tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fafafa;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bubble_chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good for bounding the container, but how do I get the circles to distribute to fill the empty space?

Comment: You mean to the right?  How do you want them to line up?

Comment: Yes I'm looking to have them distribute evenly and fill the available space. So this may require a dynamic resizing of the bubbles